# Can't send a UIButton event to other view controller correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

Can someone provide some examples and formal patterns for one-to-one event transfer between `UIViewController`s? I think `NSNotificationCenter` is not applicable for this use case because it is based on event bus and broadcasting patterns for broad state changes and that's why should be used for one-to-many transfers. I know that `KVO` is not applicable in this case **at all** too, because it is usually used for communication between model and controller layers in classical `MVC` realm. So now I know only one way for one-to-one event transfers: delegate pattern. But may be there are even more elegant and `simple` [not](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy) `easy` solutions.

Comment: need to use delegates..

Comment: Even protocol will work.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

In the view the action is sent to:

```
@protocol MapViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void)MapImageButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender;

@end

@interface MapView : UIView
{
    UIButton    *mapButton;
    id          mapViewDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)     id              mapViewDelegate;
@property(nonatomic,retain)     UIButton        *mapButton;
```

.m

```
  [mapButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(mapImageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

In the view the action will be sent from:

```
#import "MapView.h"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MapViewDelegate>
{

}

.m

MapView *map = [[MapView alloc] init];
map.delegate = self;

-(void)MapImageButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
 //implement the necessary functionality here
}
```

Hope you get the idea. Please implement it according to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that method in a protocol in your view's interface:

```
@protocol MyViewWithButtonDelegateProtocol<NSObject>

-(void)myButtonAction:(id)sender; @end
```

- you put a new property of NSObject or UIView type called delegate in your view
  that has the button.
- you make your view that has to handle the action comply to that
  protocol and when it inits the view assign the delegate property to
  self.
- you implement myButtonAction in your view controller implementation.
- and now you just do [myButton setTarget:delegate
  action:@selector(myButtonAction:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];.